# benefits and usage of export as statement for exporting modules on javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm learning Javascript ES6 on codecademy and there´s a lesson about *named exports* and *export as* statement.  For example:

```
export { specialty as chefsSpecial, isVegetarian as isVeg};
```

My question is about what are the benefits of using *export as* rather than *named exports* like:

```
export let specialty = '';
```

or

```
export { specialty, isVegetarian };
```

So far my thought is that *export as* could be used for variable names standarization  in projects, but haven´t come up with further advantages on makeing use of it.

also, do developers make use of this *export as* functionality? I´ve tried to get answers on the web but everything that's about *exports* and *imports* doesn't mention anything about *export as* .

Comment: Using `as` just allows you to define the symbol name of the export if you want it to be different than the name is locally.

Comment: Yeah, in my experience I haven't used `export as` much, but I use `import as` quite often, so that for example I can use a naming schema appropriate to my application that's different than how the module is exported as.

Answer (score 0):

Using `as` just allows you to define the symbol name of the export if you want it to be different than the name is locally.

So your publicly exported symbol name can be something different than you use locally.

> My question is about what are the benefits of using `export as` rather than named exports like:

There's no particular benefit if you're happy with the internal name being the same as the exported name.  If you want a different exported name, you can either rename everything locally to the new name or use `export as` to change just the name of the exported symbol.

> So far my thought is that export as could be used for variable names standarization in projects, but haven´t come up with further advantages on makeing use of it.

I could imagine it being convenient to centralize the definition of the exported symbols in one place without forcing the definition of the functions themselves to be all in one place.  If you were designing the code originally to be exported and publicly reusable, then you'd probably just name things from the beginning with an appropriate exported name and not use `export as`.  But, if you had a body of existing code that you were now trying to put a wrapper around and for various reasons you didn't want to rename a lot of things internally, I could see some convenience to using `export as`.

Keep in mind that it's just a syntactical convenience.  These two scenarios are functionally equivalent:

```
function sayGreeting() {
    console.log("hi");
}

const greet = sayGreeting;

export greet;
```

And this:

```
function sayGreeting() {
    console.log("hi");
}

export {sayGreeting as greet};
```

---

Or, of course you could have just written it like this in the first place:

```
export function greet() {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

---

Personally, I agree with Geuis that `import as` is more useful than `export as` and the canonical use for `import as` is when you're importing two modules that both define the same symbol name (a name collision which can happen in the real world), then you can use `import as` to change the local symbol name to something that does not conflict with the other module you are importing.

---

This is the best reference article I've found on import and export syntax:

[ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)